# CSS dotted border renders as dashed in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I applied "border-bottom:#F60 dotted .3em;" to a div and while Firefox renders the dots as round, Chrome shows them as blocky dashes. Any takers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it's important that the borders are the same you can look into the CSS3 border image property: http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/ for Chrome it will be `-webkit-border-image:`

Comment: If there's isn't a way to force Chrome to render dotted then this would be the solution. Thank you.

Comment: it seem this is the best solution

Answer (score 3):

The specification doesn't define what 'dotted' means to that level of detail. The two browsers just interpret it differently. [This is not a problem](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/).

Comment: If the border is part of the style then it does matter.

Comment: Then tell the designer it's a limitation!

Comment: It's not a limitation since it can be achieved via various methods, it just can't be achieved with `border: dotted`

Comment: Update: The spec now does specify what dotted means: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#dotted.

Comment: hhhhhhhh link awesome

Answer (score 2):

As a graphic designer, this is indeed a problem for me.

`:dotted;` and `:dashed;` are specified separately for a reason - a rectangle is not a circle. While it is possible to work around, web builders working at a remove often don't spot the difference. As far as they are concerned, the brief has been met.
to be fair, at 1px, it is less of a problem but when heavier weight dotted lines are used as design elements and code is selected over graphics to save on page load, things can go quite wrong.

**For those needing a single dotted line that absolutely has to be a true dotted line**, I would suggest a div with a small repeating background image. Could also try styling up a `<ul>` if you want to keep it all code.